# T-SQL prompt before dropping table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF DB_ID('AP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP DATABASE AP
GO

CREATE DATABASE AP
GO
```

Is there a command to make it such that before `DROP DATABASE AP`, the user/DBA is prompted to confirm?

Comment: nope. there isn't any.

Comment: That's application behaviour, not SQL behaviour.

Comment: There is nothing built in, potentially you could create a table "##Confirmation" then print out an insert statement that the user should execute as confirmation and loop until confirmation received or timeout expired.

Comment: A [DDL Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) could catch the operation, but confirmation remains problematic. The trigger could prevent the operation if another action hasn't been taken, e.g. setting [`Session_Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) key `'ConfirmDrop'` to the name of the database to be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL language is internally executed in the database service of your DBMS and cannot interfer with any Human Machine Interface. The only service that a DBMS is able is to receive queries and respond to them. It is to your application to do so.
If you are using SSMS, you can use the HMI to have such a comportment.

Comment: I've removed "A+" from your posts. See [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/284827).

Comment: What do you mean by HMI? Can you elaborate on this Please.

Comment: HMI = Human Machine Interface aka windows, dialog boxes and so on.